# Werkzeug http route rewrite

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, werkzeug, odoo-9, odoo-website

I want to make a kind of "main route" so I get it on every page. I want to add few operations with url before redirection to the specific route.

What url mask should i use to catch all urls?

```
@http.route(['/any_url_here'])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@http.route([
             '/',
             '/<path:path>',
             ], type='http', auth="public", website=True)
def anything(self, **post):
    ...
```

Comment: mh, it does for me. did you try putting a breakpoint inside **anything** ? does it enter? also, declare the urls you are trying